# Array is empty after a foreach loop (async/await)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, async-await

I'm trying to retrieve an array of cards for a project. However, in my function, the final `contacts` array returns an empty array.
I know that, because I have an async call to another funcion inside the forEach loop, the loop doesn't execute as intended. However, I'm very newbie when it comes to deal with this issues, so I want to ask you what's the best approach to deal with this.
This is my code:

```
export const extractsIDSForUser = async (currentUser: User) : Promise <Object> => {
    let contactCards = currentUser.contacts;
    const contacts = [];
    const usersRef =  await firebase.firestore().collection('Users').get();
    const usersSnapshot = usersRef.docs.map(doc => doc.data());

    contactCards.forEach(async folder => {
        const ids = [];

        folder.forEach(contact => {
            ids.push(contact);
        });
        
        for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i +=1) {
            const contact = ids[i];

            for (let j = 0; j < usersSnapshot.length; j += 1) {
                const userId = usersSnapshot[j].id;

                // Async call to function
                const cardsFromUser = await extractCardsFromUser(userId);
                const arrayCards = Object.values(cardsFromUser);

                if (arrayCards.length > 0) {
                    for (let j = 0; j < arrayCards.length; j += 1) {
                        const arrayId = arrayCards[j].id;
                        const sameCardId = arrayId === contact;
    
                        if (sameCardId) {
                            // Where I insert the values into the array
                            contacts.push(arrayCards[j]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // this is empty
    return contacts;
}
```

What will be the best approach to deal with this?

Comment: you have nested forEach so it's not working as you expected or in order you want. Convert folder.forEach to standard for loop

Comment: You promise chain is broken at `contactCards.forEach(async folder => {` the arrow function in `forEach` returns a promise that resolves as soon as the code in the callback is finished. But `forEach` doesn’t do anything with that, so the „outer“ code won’t wait until the Code executed in the callback of the `forEach` finishs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have already found a solution, but I had a similar problem and found [this article](https://blog.devgenius.io/using-async-await-in-a-foreach-loop-you-cant-c174b31999bd) quite helpful.

You could use a traditional `for (const contactCard of contactCards)` and it will work, but it will be less efficient than using a `Promise.all` approach.